# How to tell if the plot indicate an over- or under-representation?

Tags: data-visualization

Lets say I have a graph like this:

[image]

How to tell if this plot indicates an over- or under-representation of male students in in-school suspensions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you need to explain how this plot was created.  What is the data, and what does it measure/represent?

Comment: Do you want to test that hypothesis, or do you just wonder how the plot shows it?

Comment: @gung I know the plot shows that there is a relation between the number of male students in each school and the number of male students who get suspended -- from what I understand, male students is more likely to get suspended. Please correct me if I am wrong. 

What I want to know is what does over/under representation means? and how can we tell if  the plot indicates over/under representation?

Comment: @MatthewDrury the data is how many male/female student in each school and how many male/female get suspended. I counted the proportion for each school of male students in a school (x axis) and proportion of male students who get suspended (y axis). I hope that helps

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your data?

Comment: What does "proportion of suspended male students mean"? It sounds like it's the fraction of male students who ever got suspended, but--judging from the data in the plot--it more likely could be something like the proportion of males among all suspended students.  And what do the counts mean?  If we are to believe the axis labels, they must correspond to a number of *schools* (which are the observation units), but what database includes tens of thousands of schools?

Answer (score 1):

"Over- / under-representation" is just an English phrase.  Basically the idea is that something is disproportionate.  If being male (or female) has nothing to do with whether you get suspended, you might expect that if a school is 30% male, about 30% of those who get suspended would be male.

Assuming the blue line is the mean proportion male of those who get suspended, if sex were unrelated to suspension, you'd expect that line to be straight along the diagonal from (0, 0) to (1, 1).  Your line is always above that diagonal (except at the two corners).  That means that the mean proportion male suspended is always greater than the proportion of male students.

Comment: Curiously, looking along the bottom of the plot to the right of center it seems there are some schools that have up to ~90% female where no males are ever suspended. I wonder what those schools are like.

Comment: "proportion male suspended is always greater than the proportion of male students". So that means it is over represented?
I wonder, how can I improve this graph so it can be clearer and easier to understand?

Comment: The blue line is a smooth line between proportion of male student in a school and proportion of male student who got suspended

Comment: @BagusTrihatmaja, yes the plot appears to show that males are overrepresented among those students suspended.